# Jest mockImplementation works in one test file, but fails in another

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
/api
  index.js
  base.js
  notebooks.js
/components
  AllNotebooks/
  NewNotebook/
/containers
  AllNotebooks/
  NewNotebook/
  common/withList/
```

I am using `jest.spyOn.mockImplementation` to mock my `notebooks.js` api, and that is working test cases for `<NewNotebookContainer />`, but it's not getting mocked for `AllNotebooksContainer`.

```
// api/base.js
const instance = axios.createinstance({url: BASE_URL})

export default instance

// api/notebooks.js
const getAll = () => instance.get("/notebooks");
const create = id => instance.post("/notebooks")

export {getAll, create}

// api/index.js
import * as notebooksApi from './notebooks'
export {notebooksApi}
```

Now, it works with

```
import NewNotebook from "../../components/NewNotebook";
import { notebooksApi } from "../../api/index";

const NewNotebookContainer = function () {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!newNotebook.title.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return notebooksApi.create(newNotebook).then(() => {
        toggleModal();
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <NewNotebook handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
  );
};

export default NewNotebookContainer;


// ./__test__/index.js

it("should invoke api if title exists", async () => {
    renderNotebook();
    const spy = jest
      .spyOn(notebooksApi, "create")
      .mockImplementation((x) => Promise.resolve(x));
    await act(() => {
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Create Notebook/ }));
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

However, the `notebookApi` doesn't get mocked with `<AllNotebooksContainer />`

```
// AllNotebooksContainer/index.js

import AllNotebooks from "../../components/AllNotebooks";
import { notebooksApi } from "../../api/index";
import withList from "../common/withList";

const AllNotebooksContainer = withList(AllNotebooks, notebooksApi.getAll);

export default AllNotebooksContainer;

// ../withList/index.js

const withList = (Component, getList) => {
  return function WithList(props) 
    useEffect(async () => {
      // invoke getList and store data in state
    }, []);

    if (!loading) {
      return <Component data={list} {...props} />;
    } else {
      return <Loading />;
    }
  };
};

// ./__test__/index.js

  it("should render correct number of <Notebook />", async () => {
    const spy = jest
      .spyOn(notebooksApi, "getAll")
      .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }));
    renderComponent();
    await waitFor(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    // some assertions
  });
```

For `<AllNotebooksContainer />` the actual method `getAll` is getting invoked, and I get `Network Error` in my terminal, and also `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` fails with `0` as the received value.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by instead mocking the whole `notebooksApi` module.

```
import {notebooksApi} from './somewhere/api/index'
jest.mock('./somewhere/api/index')
```

then in my test cases I used it as,

```
notebooksApi.getAll.mockResolvedvalue({data: mockData})
expect(notebooksApi.getAll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

I still don't understand the weird behavior earlier with `jest.spyOn`, I'll keep looking into it and update the answer accordingly.